# Activity class {} does not exist. emulator

Tags: android, react-native

Boa tarde.
Estou com esse problema à 3 dias. Quando tento instalar a debugRelease no emulador ocorre o seguinte erro:

```
error type 3 Error: 
Activity class {com.marktclub/com.marktclub.MainActivity} does not exist. emulator
```

Ao gerar a release normal (./gradlew assembleRelease) ele não da erro. O problema é só ao tentar passar pro emulador.

Já tentei o comando e não funcionou:

> adb uninstall com.marktclub

Esse problema ocorreu depois que deletei o emulador e criei um novo.

Comment: Tente instalar o apk direto com o comando: `adb install app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk`

Comment: Essa [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36489156/9671639) do SOen pode resolver também

Comment: Instalando direto deu o mesmo erro e verifiquei todos os arquivos e todos estão com o mesmo nome do app correto. =/